# VueJS Render VNode

Tags: javascript, vue.js, datatables, vuejs2

### tl;dr:

Given a VueJS `VNode` object, how do I get the HTML element that would be generated if it were rendered?

e.g.:

```
> temp1
VNode {tag: "h1", data: undefined, children: Array(1), text: undefined, elm: undefined, …}
> temp1.children[0]
VNode {tag: undefined, data: undefined, children: undefined, text: "Test", elm: undefined, …}
> doSomething(temp1)
<h1>Test</h1>
```

### Goal

I'm attempting to build a small VueJS wrapper around the [DataTables.net](https://datatables.net/) library.

To mimic the behavior of HTML tables in my markup, I want something like the following:

```
<datatable>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Age</th>
            <th>Salary</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <datatable-row v-for="person in people">
            <td>{{ person.name }}</td>
            <td>{{ person.age }}</td>
            <td>{{ person.salary }}</td>
        </datatable-row>
    </tbody>
</datatable>
```

### What I've done so far

I've started to implement this as follows:

**DataTable.vue**

```
<template>
    <table ref="table" class="display table table-striped" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
        <slot></slot>
    </table>
</template>

<script>
/* global $ */
export default {
    data: () => ({
        instance: null
    }),
    mounted() {
        this.instance = $(this.$refs.table).dataTable();
        this.$el.addEventListener("dt.row_added", function(e) {
            this.addRow(e.detail);
        });
    },
    methods: {
        addRow(row) {
            // TODO <-----
            console.log(row);
        }
    }
};
</script>
```

**DataTableRow.vue**

```
<script>
/* global CustomEvent */
export default {
    mounted() {
        this.$nextTick(() => {
            this.$el.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent("dt.row_added", {
                bubbles: true,
                detail: this.$slots.default.filter(col => col.tag === "td")
            }));
        });
    },
    render() { return ""; }
};
```

### What this currently does:

- When the page loads, the DataTable is initialized. So the column headers are properly formatted and I see "Showing 0 to 0 of 0 entries" in the bottom left
- The `CustomEvent` is able to bubble up past the `<tbody>` and be caught by the `DataTable` element **successfully** (circumventing the limitation in VueJS that you can't listen to events on slots)

### What this does **not** do:

- Actually add the row

My event is giving me an array of `VNode` objects. There's one `VNode` per column in my row. The DataTables API has an `addRow` function which can be called like so:

```
this.instance.row.add(["col1", "col2", "col3"]);
```

In my case, I want the resultant element from the rendering of the VNode to be the elements in this array.

```
var elems = [];
for (var i = 0; i < row.length; i++)
    elems[i] = compile(row[i]);
this.instance.row.add(elems);
```

Unfortunately this `compile` method eludes me. I tried skimming the VueJS documentation and I tried Googling it, but no dice. I tried manually passing the `createElement` function (the parameter passed to the `render` method) but this threw an error. How can I ask VueJS to render a VNode without injecting the result into the DOM?

Answer (score 7):

I ran into the same issue wanting to do basically the same thing with a row details template for DataTables.net.

One solution could be to create a generic component that renders out a `VNode` and instantiate that programmatically.  Here is how my setup for a dynamic detail row that I insert using datatable's `row.child()` API.

**RenderNode.js**

```
export default {
    props: ['node'],
    render(h, context) {
        return this.node ? this.node : ''
    }
}
```

**Datatables.vue**

Include the renderer component from above

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import nodeRenderer from './RenderNode'
```

Instantiate and mount the renderer to get the compiled HTML

```
// Assume we have `myVNode` and want its compiled HTML

const DetailConstructor = Vue.extend(nodeRenderer)

const detailRenderer = new DetailConstructor({
    propsData: {
        node: myVNode
    }
})

detailRenderer.$mount()    
// detailRenderer.$el is now a compiled DOM element 
row.child(detailRenderer.$el).show()
```

Answer (score -2):

You should define your components like with:

```js
import {createApp} from 'vue';
import {defineAsyncComponent} from "vue";

createApp({
    components: {
        'top-bar': defineAsyncComponent(() => import('@Partials/top-bar'))
    }
}).mount("#app")
```

Comment: It doesn’t make sense, that’s an async component not a vnode