# Render VNode to html string

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm developing a Vue server-side templating engine, and part of the package includes a head management system.

I'm developing a Server-Side Renderer for Vue and for the SSR's head management to work, it needs a way to render `VNode`s to text.

**My Question:**
how can I render VNode(s) into a string? For example:

`this.$ssrContext.head = renderVNodesToString(this.$slots.head)`

**Example use case:**

`master.vue`

```
<template>
    <div id="app">
        <slot name="content"></slot>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
    created: function(){
        if(this.$isServer){
            var VNodesToRender = this.$slots.head
            this.$ssrContext.head = 'rendered VNode here'
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

`home.vue`

```
<template>
    <master>
        <template slot="content">
            Hello World
        </template>
        <template slot="head">
            <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
            <title>Hello</title>
        </template>
    </master>
</template>
<script>
import master from "layouts/master.vue"

export default {
    components: {
        master
    }
}
</script>
```

My goal is getting `home.vue`'s `head` slot rendered into a string and injecting it into the `this.$ssrContext` so it can be read and injected on the server-side

in `master.vue`, I can access `this.$slots.head` with no issue, and it contains the correct `VNode`s

**Where the string is used**

in `{{{ head }}}`

```
const renderer = createBundleRenderer(bundle.server, {
    runInNewContext: false,
    inject: false,
    template: `<!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
            <head>
                {{{ head }}}
                {{{ renderResourceHints() }}}
                {{{ renderStyles() }}}
            </head>
            <body>
                <!--vue-ssr-outlet-->
                <script>${ bundle.client }</script>
            </body>
       </html>`
})
```

**Note:**
This question is not like:

1. [VueJS Render VNode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50556294/vuejs-render-vnode)
2. [Understanding Vnodes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51368392/understanding-vnodes)
3. [Can you render VNodes in a Vue template?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49352525/can-you-render-vnodes-in-a-vue-template)

as it requires a string output, which is passed to the SSR

Comment: I think what you're looking for is [located in the vue ssr docs](https://ssr.vuejs.org/guide/#rendering-a-vue-instance). It's probably the `vue-server-renderer` package. Seems to be able to render anything down.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy, unfortunately, that can't help. I'm already using it to render the .vue files. I'm trying to pass a variable from the .vue file to the $ssrContext